# How to play sound on click without waiting for the previous sound to finish playing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I got a sound on click, on a button. But I can't rapidly spam the button to hear that sound over and over again, instead I have to wait until the sound is over to play it again. How can I let the sound, when playing, get interrupted by a new click, playing the sound from the start?

```
<script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }           
   </script>

<button onclick="play()">
     <audio id="audio" src="bell.ogg" ></audio> </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `currentTime` property, and take the `<audio>` tag outside the `<button>`

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function playSound() {
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="playSound()">Play!</button>
<audio id="audio" src="https://www.kozco.com/tech/piano2-CoolEdit.mp3"></audio>
```